# Spring 3 - export data in csv format

Tags: spring, csv

I have some data in the DB and would like to be able to export it to a CSV file and provide a link so the user can download it.

Is there any mechanism provided by Spring 3 for this?

Do you know how could I do that?

Comment: Spring doesn't provide CSV support. There are plenty CSV libraries for Java, though (just search for "java csv").

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I guess it should be easy to build a CSV or any text file view.  Here are suggested steps:

1. Create a View class (you can name it as `CSVView`) extending `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView`
2. Override `renderMergedOutputModel` as follows (pseudo code):

> `BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(response.getWriter())`
>
> `response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"file.csv\"");`
>
> `myDbData = (Whatever) modelMap.get("modelKey");`
>
> `some kind of loop {writer.write(myDbData csv row); writer.newLine(); }`
>
> `finally writer.flush(); writer.close();`

After that just return ModelAndView with model (object `Whatever` with `modelKey`) and view as `CSVView` in the controller.

Comment: an alternative solution can be found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913732/configuring-spring-mvc-controller-to-send-file-to-client, but it's a matter of taste.