# how to download a csv file written in local computer using java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to download a csv file after creating it. The file is being written in download folder but user not able to see it as downloaded file . I am using the following code. I want after write this file should be displayed as downloaded file.

```
      try (
              PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\Downloads\\downloadCSV.csv")))

            {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


  sb.append("RollNo,");
  sb.append("Name,");
  sb.append("Marks,");
  sb.append('\n');
  sb.append("4053,");
  sb.append("rahul,");
 sb.append("55,");
  sb.append('\n');
  sb.append("4055,");
  sb.append("anil,");
  sb.append("56,");
  writer.write(sb.toString());
   System.out.println("done!");

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: If it's being written to that folder, and you've verified it's there, what else do you want? What do you mean "displayed as a downloaded file"?

Comment: when i click on hyperlink the file is written but i want the file should be downloaded may be after temporary file creation it may download

Comment: So that's a servlet? It would be useful if you give a bit more context by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: this is being created in controller of spring

Comment: This code sends it to the download folder. It will be put together with the other downloads, and it can be visualized through the file Explorer. It won't show on the browser's download list, since it wasn't dowloaded by it. The question is: why do you want to do this?

Comment: In order for it to show up *in the browser* as a downloaded file you'd have to *request it through the browser* and download it normally. The presence of a file in a download folder is meaningless to the browser--the browser only tracks what it does. And if the server isn't running on the same machine as the browser, I'm not even sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Okay, so you want the Spring controller to return the file as a download?

Answer (score 2):

Basically from what I understand you need to put in your spring controller
`Content-Disposition` header as part from response header.

Here is more information about that header
[Content-Disposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) and a way how you can wrap in your [spring controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913732/configuring-spring-mvc-controller-to-send-file-to-client).

Basically with that header you force the browser to download (or to view) the file.
You will probably need to set one more additional header `Content-Type`.

Comment: Do not forget to copy the file to the request's `OutputStream`.

Comment: yeah defenetly ty